# Worklight MBS in Internet Explorer not displaying properly

Tags: internet-explorer, ibm-mobilefirst

When I use Worklight's MBS (Mobile Browser Simulator), or RPE (Rich Page Editor) using Internet Explorer v8, images and other content are not displaying properly or not displaying at all.  Is there a setting or some information on running the Worklight MBS on internet Explorer? I have both Worklight 5.0.5 and 5.0.6 environments. Thanks!

Jeff

Comment: When you say emulator, do you mean the mobile browser simulator?

Comment: Yes, thanks.  When you select run as -> Preview, the simulator will start up.

Comment: Fixed up the question a bit. Can you you or link to a screen shot exhibiting what you you have mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

According to IBM documentation, [IE is not a supported browser for the MBS](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.webtoolscore.doc/topics/cmbs.html).
Only Firefox 3.6+ and Chrome 17+.

As for the RPE, [see the documentation as well](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.etools.rpe.doc%2Ftopics%2Ftrpebrowsersupport.html). Add screen shots and also the mark-up and CSS that you use for the images. Perhaps something is amiss there.